# In Element-ui,click the elect or checkbox in dialog shaking

Tags: vue.js

There is a demo

http://jsfiddle.net/sqghggak/

When I click the checkbox or select it, it takes a shake. How can I fix it?

I tried to add `overflow: scroll` this to the .el-dialog__wrapper, but it was useless.

Comment: It seems fine to me. I do not notice any shaking.

Comment: It seems fine in firefox.Chrome has this bug.

Answer (score 0):

ok,I got the same error

```
<el-dialog title="权限设置" v-model="isShowPermission" style="overflow: scroll">          
        <div v-for="sub of permissions">

            <el-checkbox @change="subchange(sub)" v-model="sub.ischeck">{{sub.subname}}</el-checkbox>

            <div style="margin-left: 20px;" v-for="sub_ of sub.subpermission">
                <el-checkbox @change="sub_change(sub,sub_)" v-model="sub_.ischeck">{{sub_.subname}}</el-checkbox>
                <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
                    <el-checkbox v-for="sub__ of sub_.subpermission" @change="sub__change(sub,sub_,sub__)"
                                 v-model="sub__.ischeck">{{sub__.subname}}
                    </el-checkbox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
            <el-button @click="isShowPermission = false" size="small">取 消</el-button>
            <el-button type="primary" size="small" @click="handleSavePermission"
                       :loading="dialogloading">确 定</el-button>
        </span>
    </el-dialog>
```

The checkbox dialog is dynamically generated.When a chebox selected,it will shake a little.
However, 'overflow: scroll' solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

try to add style below to avoid this problem, it works for me :)

```
.el-select .el-input {
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```